# Mongoose/Mongodb: Index Already Exists With Different Options

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I am using Mongoose 5.1.7 and attempting to create a compound index across multiple text indexes in my defined schema. Here is my schema definition:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const alumniSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  classYear: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  photoURL: {
    type: String,
  },
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      gradYear: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      degreeType: String,
      degreeSubject: String,
    }
  ],
  jobs: [
    {
      employer: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      position: String,
      startDate: Date,
      endDate: Date,
      isCurrent: Boolean
    }
  ],
  contactInfo: {
    phoneNumber: {
      type: String,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
    }
  },
})

alumniSchema.index({ firstName: 'text', lastName : 'text', email: 'text' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Alumni', alumniSchema);
```

When I boot up the server, I receive the following error:

```
MongoError: Index: { v: 2, key: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 }, name: "firstName_text_lastName_text_email_text", ns: "5b3be578c0c6e317f7c1bc2b_test.alumnis", background: true, weights: { email: 1, firstName: 1, lastName: 1 }, default_language: "english", language_override: "language", textIndexVersion: 3 } already exists with different options: { v: 2, key: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 }, name: "firstName_text_lastName_text_classYear_text_education.school_text", background: true, weights: { classYear: 1, education.school: 1, firstName: 1, lastName: 1 }, default_language: "english", language_override: "language", ns: "5b3be578c0c6e317f7c1bc2b_test.alumnis", textIndexVersion: 3 }
```

I have been messing around with this for a while and evidently previously created an index. When I use the mongo shell to check the indexes that I currently have set up, however, I cannot find the index "firstName_text_lastName_text_classYear_text_education.school_text" referenced by the error message:

```
> db
test
> db.collection.getIndexes()
[ ]
```

I am at an impasse--I'm not sure if I've incorrectly created the index, or if I am supposed to drop the index (it doesn't look like Mongoose natively supports a dropIndex() function).

Has anyone else dealt with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Mongoose dynamically creates the index at runtime. The trick for me was adding:

```
var Alumni = mongoose.model('Alumni', alumniSchema);
Alumni.collection.dropIndex('firstName_text_lastName_text_classYear_text_education.school_text', function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error dropping index!', err);
    }
});
```

and then restarting the server.

THEN I was able to change the index to whatever I wanted. Note that I still needed to add the above code segment and restart the server every time I wanted to update the index.

Comment: This is the answer. I started with an index list of `a_text_b_text` and tried to add `c_text`, which on server restart, would try to apply `a_text_b_text_c_text` which would "obviously" fail due to the first two indices already existing. After dropping the first two, it simply recreated the dropped indicies and added `c_text`.